# Javascript CSS rule error when reloading the page

Tags: javascript

I'm inserting lots of CSS rules with Javascript on my website.

Something like the following:

```
let styleSheet = document.styleSheets[document.styleSheets.length - 1];

styleSheet.insertRule('hr,img{border:0 }', styleSheet.cssRules.length);

styleSheet.insertRule('a,input{outline:0!important }', styleSheet.cssRules.length); 

...
```

It is working fine in the beginning. However I noticed that when I try to reload the page or enter the same url in the same browser tab, it breaks the page and nothing's being displayed properly. Here's the error I get

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from
'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
```

I have found out though, that if I enable the `disable caching` feature in Chrome Dev tools, then everything works properly and I don't ever get any error.

Does anyone know why is this happening and how can I resolve this?

If you need more details, I'll include, just ask for it please.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are inserting CSS via JavaScript instead of creating a CSS file then loading it?

Comment: @jeff Yes, I'm doing it to dynamically set back CSS styles (to their default values) that have been (purposefully) written wrongly. I know I could do that via CSS also, but I don't want the visitor to be able to see these CSS rules in CSS files.

Comment: The Dev Tools and computed styles will show the 'correct' values. I think that you are making more, unnecessary, work for yourself - but hey.

Comment: @jeff Yeah I know, I do this on purpose to make it harder for people with basic knowledge to read, modify things. And it is working out pretty good. But there are times when the page is not reloaded properly.